# Routing ( route command ) between two Network Cards

Tags: networking, 18.04, network-manager, lan, wwan

I got stuck with this network situation with my workwhere I need some of your advice, Please help

Server : Ubuntu 18.04

Two network Card .

Nic 1 :

eth0 ( Has Access to Internet )

```
eth0
    IP: 172.16.16.12 / 24

    Default Gw : 172.16.16.1
```

2nd Network Card ( not connected to the Internet ) :

```
eth1
    IP: 192.178.10.12 / 24

    Gateway : 192.178.10.10
```

Server has default gateway set up for eth0 and its gateway connected to the internet.

Et1 card is connected to internal Network and must receive Ip stream from internal hosts but since the server gateway is configure for eth0 , it doesn't receive any stream from Internal network.

can you please help me here with this situation to set some route settings via route command ?

basically, I want to receive the internal stream via `ETH1` and send this stream out via `ETH0`

> edited : I check with TCPDUMP, after setting up default gateway with
>   WAN , Linux Box receive the traffic at internal Network card but can't
>   send back the ACK so tcp Connection doesn't start.Hope this helps.

Thank you very much for any tip /advice.

Comment: you have *two* gateways defined.  Remove your gateway definition for your 2nd non-Internet card.  You can only have one Gateway enabled.

Comment: I have already deleted the gateway and it still doesn't work.